# Can I keep base64 data in a file and use it in HTML

Tags: html

For example, can I store a data:image/png;base64,iVBOR... instead of iVBOR... on the server and use it in HTML?

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <img src="data:image/png;base64,url(./encode.b64)">
   </body>
</html>
```

Can I store and use base64 code on the server?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is. You can have a `data:` uri in your HTML code, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme. What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no - you can't do it with HTML only (without using Javascript). URL scheme `data` is designed to embed files into elements inline (see [RFC documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397#section-2), [Basics of HTTP by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs)).

However, it would be possible to store base64 encoded files on your server, read them with Javascript and embed inline dynamically.